# Select option and append text in textarea

Tags: jquery, select

I want to make a function that:

If the user selects the specific option in the select dropdown list, some text will be added to the textarea.

If the user selects other option in select, the textarea will be cleared.

I have tried this:

**HTML**

```
<select name="Problem" id="Problem">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
<textarea name="csContent" id="csContent">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
    if ($('#Problem').val() == '3') {
        $('#csContent').html('blahblahblah');           
    } else {
        $('#csContent').val('');
    }
});
```

However this doesn't work. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What's '3'? Don't you mean 'option3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a *conditional operator (?:)* is quite nice and easy:

***[demo](http://jsbin.com/EtulodO/2/edit)***

```
$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
  $('#csContent').html( this.value.match("n3") ? "blahblahblah" : "" );
});
```

<sub>Note: .match("n3") (searching for occurence "n3" in your value) method might also match `option32`.  If you need to be more specific than use:

 `this.value === "option3" ? "blahblahblah" : ""`</sub>

Comment: If the option might be many languages, I want to point it by the option order, not the text in option, Can it possible to do? Thx.

Comment: you can use `:eq()` (you need to take a look at the docs) and `.index()` make a research. (P.S I don't quite understand what you're asking)

Comment: sorry for my poor english. Is it use like this? `$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
  $('#csContent').html( this.value.index(3) ? "blahblahblah" : "" );
});`

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine , change the value `3` to `option3`.

```
<select name="Problem" id="Problem">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
<textarea name="csContent" id="csContent"></textarea>
```

```
$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'option3') {
        $('#csContent').val('blahblahblah');           
    } else {
        $('#csContent').val('');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/78r3m/4/)

The value you specified(`3`) is not matching the value of any dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

The value check is incorrect. It should be checked against `option3` instead of just `3`

```
$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'option3') {
        $('#csContent').html('blahblahblah');           
    } else {
        $('#csContent').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, since you're using wrong value

```
$('#problem').val() == '3'
```

will never b e true since there is no such value.

Use this:

```
if ($('#Problem').val() == 'option3') {
  $('#csContent').html('blahblahblah');           
} else {
  $('#csContent').val('');
}
```

The issue was only `3` replace it with `option3` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/FNaA9/

```
$("#Problem").on("change", function () {
if ($(this).val() == 'option3') {
    $('#csContent').html('blahblahblah');           
} else {
    $('#csContent').html('');
}
});
```

Notice .val in the else statement has changed to .html

This is also important as otherwise you can only change the item once (try changing to option 3 - then option 1 then option 3 again on other answers - it won't update the text box the second time)

Comment: Instead of re-caching the selector use `this.value == "option3"`